# flutter The instance member 'lat' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter 3 I'm trying to pass a a value, but it throws an error indicating `The instance member 'lat' can't be accessed in an initializer.`. i've been away from flutter since the version 3. the problem i'm having is I've created an initializer

```
late double lat;
late double long;
```

then i assigned the value in `initState()`

```
@override
  void initState() async {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Position position = await _determinePosition();
    lat = position.latitude;
    lat = position.longitude;
  }

  final myCoordinates = Coordinates(lat, long); //this line is the error
```

when i try to pass the `lat`  and `long` to mycoordinates it throws an error `The instance member 'myCoordinates' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`.

How else can i pass this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the order in which your object will be created:

1. Object is created
2. All final member variables are initialized
3. Flutter will run initState

you need to put your initialize your coordinates in initState:

```
@override
  void initState() async {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Position position = await _determinePosition();
    lat = position.latitude;
    lat = position.longitude;
    myCoordinates = Coordinates(lat, long); // move the initialization here
  }

  final late myCoordinates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking it late should probably solve it for you:

```
late final myCoordinates = Coordinates(lat, long);
```